# Storing objects and Arrays in Core Data

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nskeyedunarchiver

I have used [Sugar Record](https://github.com/carambalabs/SugarRecord) (core data framework) for app backend. Now I need to store a object (DTO object or DTO object Array) into the table. 
So far I have tried to archive & stored using `NSKeyedArchiver` , but when I un-archive it with `NSKeyedUnarchiver` after fetching, ** the result object properties are nil**.

Model class :

```
@NSManaged public var cakeId: String?
@NSManaged public var cakeName: String?
@NSManaged public var selectedCake: Data? //I need to store/archive this 'HOCakesDto' object.
```

Inside Cakes DTO :

```
class HOCakesDto : NSObject, NSCoding {

    public var vendorId : String?
    public var vendor : String?
    public var createDate : String?

//Rest of my code ...


}
```

Is this a wrong approach? How can I fix this in Swift?

Thanks for the any inputs.

Comment: Isn't it more reasonable to make `HOCakesDto` an entity, too?

Comment: @vadian Wish I could. `HOCakesDto` is actually JSON response mapper object. and I don't want to store. Anyway, suppose If I store do I need to fetch from the foreign key?

Comment: If `cakes` is designed as a relationship the instances are included when fetching the *Model class* entity.